# Export, Import and extra curly brackets?

Tags: list-manipulation, export, import

```
list= {{}, {200, 200, 200}, {}, {201, 201}};
Export["list.csv", {list}, "csv"]
data = Import["lnumber.csv", "csv"];
```

The result of this export and import is an extra curly bracket.

```
 (* data -> {{{}, {200, 200, 200}, {}, {201, 201}}} *)
```

(Note:without " "in output).

However, I want `{200, 200, 200, 201, 201}`.

`Flatten[data]` doesn't give the desired result.
One way to overcome the problem is to `Flatten[list]` before exporting.

But, I want to `Flatten[data]` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your usage of `"CSV"` export is incorrect: exported list of numbers should be a 2D numerical array, while with `{list}` you supply a 3D array. With correct `"CSV"` format you can use advanced `Import` options:

```
list = {{}, {200, 200, 200}, {}, {201, 201}};
Export["list.csv", list, "CSV"];
data = Import["list.csv", "Table", "FieldSeparators" -> ","]
```

> ```
> {{}, {200, 200, 200}, {}, {201, 201}}
> ```

```
Flatten[%]
```

> ```
> {200, 200, 200, 201, 201}
> ```

Note that in version 8.0.4 the following does the job even better :

```
Import["list.csv", "CSV", "IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True]
```

> ```
> {{200, 200, 200}, {201, 201}}
> ```

For some reason in versions 11.2.0 and 11.3.0 the option `"IgnoreEmptyLines" -> True` does nothing, what looks like a bug.

Answer (score 3):

> However, I want {200, 200, 200, 201, 201}

Try

```
 data=Import["list.csv","CSV"]
 Flatten@ToExpression[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

A few points. First, you are not importing the same file that you're exporting. Is that intentional?

Secondly, the extra bracket is due to the extra bracket in the `Export` line:

```
Export["list.csv", {list}, "csv"]
```

Is not exactly the same as:

```
Export["list.csv", list, "csv"]
```

The latter exports `list` in .csv format, while the former exports a list containing `list` in .csv format. If you make that change, the extra bracket will disappear.

With that change, it is worth noting that the empty lists are imported as `{""}` (check `FullForm[data]` to see for yourself). This will result in spurious empty spaces showing up in `Flatten[data]`. `DeleteCases` can be used to clean it up:

```
DeleteCases[Flatten[data],""]
```

Comment: Sorry for the typo in filename. And thanks for the detailed answer.